# spring data mongodb: graphlookup query does not contain as-field

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to impement this query in spring data mongoDB:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate(
    [ 
        { "$graphLookup": { 
            "from": "myCollection", 
            "startWith": "$name", 
            "connectFromField": "name", 
            "connectToField": "parent", 
            "as": "descendants"
        }},
        { "$match": { "name": "someValue" } }, 
    ]
)

   GraphLookupOperation graphLookupOperation = GraphLookupOperation.builder()                    .from(mongoOperations.getCollectionName(MyCollection.class))
                    .startWith("name")
                    .connectFrom("name")
                    .connectTo("parent")
                    .as("descendants");
            MatchOperation matchStage = Aggregation.match(new Criteria("name").is("someValue));
            Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(graphLookupOperation, matchStage);
            List<ClassDefinitionDocument> results = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation, mongoOperations.getCollectionName(MyCollection.class), MyCollection.class).getMappedResults();
```

However, the `results` list does not contain the `descendants` field. The javascript query works perfectly in the mongo shell.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got mine working. You can try this to get it working for you.

> A TypedAggregation is a special Aggregation that holds information of
>   the input aggregation type.

```
public void graphLookupShouldBeAppliedCorrectly() {

    assumeTrue(mongoVersion.isGreaterThanOrEqualTo(THREE_DOT_FOUR));

    Employee em1 = Employee.builder().id(1).name("Dev").build();
    Employee em2 = Employee.builder().id(2).name("Eliot").reportsTo("Dev").build();
    Employee em4 = Employee.builder().id(4).name("Andrew").reportsTo("Eliot").build();

    mongoTemplate.insert(Arrays.asList(em1, em2, em4), Employee.class);

    TypedAggregation<Employee> agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(Employee.class,
            match(Criteria.where("name").is("Andrew")), //
            Aggregation.graphLookup("employee") //
                    .startWith("reportsTo") //
                    .connectFrom("reportsTo") //
                    .connectTo("name") //
                    .depthField("depth") //
                    .maxDepth(5) //
                    .as("reportingHierarchy"));

    AggregationResults<Document> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, Document.class);

    Document object = result.getUniqueMappedResult();
    List<Object> list = (List<Object>) object.get("reportingHierarchy");

    assertThat(object, isBsonObject().containing("reportingHierarchy", List.class));
    assertThat((Document) list.get(0), isBsonObject().containing("name", "Dev").containing("depth", 1L));
    assertThat((Document) list.get(1), isBsonObject().containing("name", "Eliot").containing("depth", 0L));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! However, I am not too happy with the unckecked cast there... but well... maybe I'll look into that a bit later.

Comment: Cast is done for the purpose of test case. aggregate() function can automatically map results to your custom type. Here is how I am doing it in my code:  Output results are mapped to SingleLevelThreadedPost.class                                                            TypedAggregation<Post> aggregationPipeline = Aggregation.newAggregation(Post.class, sortOperation, graphLookupOperation);
        List<SingleLevelThreadedPost> threadedPosts = operations.aggregate(aggregationPipeline, SingleLevelThreadedPost.class).getMappedResults();

Comment: my mappedResults only contain the top-level element but not the descendants field. I can only ee that field in the raw results, but in the raw results, all elements in the list are BSON documents and not my entity classes.

Comment: Can you post the code for Mapped class? Does it contain reportingHierarchy field?

Comment: Hi, I got it to work now. It's a bit strange... I would really like this to work without having to add a new field to my entity class.